# Ubuntu 18.04: How to remove extra invisible desktop space when using multiple rows of monitors?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

I just switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04. I have two rows of monitors, three in one row and another one above. See the image below  which shows my monitor configuration.
[image: display arrangement]

The problem is that the space on the sides of monitor #2 and above monitor #3 and #1 seems to be treated as extra desktop space, but I can't normally see it. I know it exists partly because it is visible if I use Chrome Remote Desktop. See the image below.
[image]
Explanation of the image: The 4 real monitors are the ones that does not have a black background. The top-right and top-left part of the image with black background is the space I want to remove/disable. You can also see some white windows that I have opened and can't normally see.

I can't move my cursor into the space. Although, I can move windows into the space and desktop icons gets placed in the space. I especially find it problematic as often when opening new windows they get placed in the invisible space, which easily gets confusing.

NOTE: The space disappears if I reorder my monitors into one row, though I did not have this problem in Windows 10 with the same configuration.

I hope I sufficiently described this problem, if not please comment on what is unclear as this is probably quite unusual. Does anyone know how to fix this?